# Script to alter html code. Preferably with a simple interface

Tags: python, html, ruby, replace

I need a script to alter a few parts of a html document. The reason I need it is because I need the same html file to be used again a lot.

My best hopes is for it (if possible to have a interface) to have the fields:

Link
[INSERT HERE]

Name
[INSERT HERE]

and so on.

[DONE BUTTON]

Then change the variables in the document to what have been specified in the input fields.

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/about to understand how the site works. Then this might also be helpful: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Would a templating library be what you're looking for? E.g. http://jinja.pocoo.org/ . Also, why have you tagged python and ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do. LEt's say you want the user to enter their own Title and content.

1) Create an interface that has 2 text boxes that will accept a Title and Content.

2) Let's say your HTML template (the one that you will be used A LOT) will look like this:

```
<html>
<title>
@Title@
</title>
<body>
Welcome to my website - @Websitecontent@
</body>
</html>
```

3) Use String.Replace that will parse and replace the @title@ and @websitecontent@ with the one that was placed in the 2 text boxes. [Here is a good documentation from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

4) Create a button in your interface named "Done" that will save the parsed template into a new HTML file.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like you want to use a templating system, as suggested in the comments (I also like and use jinja (good stuff)).

Here is a simpler example

```
title = "My Page"
html = '''

<html>
<head>
<title>{0}</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>

'''.format(title)
print html
```